# Connecting midpoints of sides of a triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

In triangle $\triangle ABC$, $AB=8$, $BC=14$ and $CA=10$. Points $M$, $N$, and $P $ are the midpoints of sides $AB$, $BC$, and $CA$, respectively. If $M$, $N$, and $P$ are connected to form a triangle, what is the perimeter of triangle $\triangle MNP$?

Comment: Do you know proportionality?

Comment: Have you tried drawing a picture?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

$\displaystyle \frac{8}{14}=\frac{4}{MP}\Rightarrow MP=7$

$\displaystyle \frac{14}{8}=\frac{7}{NP}\Rightarrow NP=4$

$\displaystyle\frac{14}{10}=\frac{7}{MN}\Rightarrow MN=5$

Perimeter$=MP+NP+MN=7+4+5=16$

Comment: It'd be easier if you prove that MN is parallel to AC and so on. Parallelogram properties after that. =)

Comment: Ah you are right. :P

Answer (score 2):

It is well known that $NPM$ is similar to $ABC$ with the scale factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ (from $ABC$ to $NPM$). The perimiter of $NPM$ is therefore $\frac{8+14+10}{2}=16$.

Answer (score 1):

I  think you need only the basic properties of middle segments (or middle lines):

**Definition:** The segment of line joining the middle points of two sides of a triangle is called middle segment.

**Lemma:** A middle segment of a triangle is parallel to the third side and its lengths is half the third side's.